# Show that the set is unbounded above

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $A$ is an uncountable subset of $[0,\infty)$. Show that the set $$\displaystyle \left \{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\ \Big|\ a_1,\ldots,a_n \in A;\ n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\right \}$$ is unbounded above.

Since $A$ is uncountable, it can't be put into a one-to-one correspondence with $\mathbb{Z^+}$. Therefore, for any $M>0$, there exists $a \in A$ such that $a > M$ and so the partial sums seem to increase without bound. This seems to be a not very rigorous argument, but can the idea be used to solve the question?

Comment: "for any $M>$" what?

Comment: @BigbearZzz Sorry, $M > 0$.

Comment: What if $A=[0,1]$? Then the statement involving $M$ seems false.

Comment: @jdods Hmm, okay I think I was misunderstanding then.

Comment: Intuitively though, an uncountable subset seems like it should have an infinite subset that is bounded below away from zero though.

Comment: As Mr. bof has pointed out, you should also mention that $a_1,...,a_n$ are supposed to be distinct, or else the question become trivial.

Comment: @bof I think that's a funny way to interpret and solve the problem. In my opinion, I don't think the OP correctly reproduced the question as he had heard it.

Comment: Basically you need to show that there are an a and  b such that 0<a <b and there are uncountable many points of A between a and b.  Thus you can have an infinite sum of points in this interval. And these sums are infinite as each term is at least a.  So reduces to showing such an interval exists.  Which should be doable.

Answer (score 2):

There needn't be $a \in A$ such that $a>M$. It's quite possible that every element of $A$ is bounded above by $1$ or $\frac{1}{2}$ or something even smaller.

Consider $A_n:=\left\{a \in A \mid a \geq \frac{1}{n}\right\}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If each $A_n$ is finite, then either $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ or $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \cup \{0\}$, both of which are countable sets. So there must exist $n$ such that $A_n$ is infinite. Now given $M>0$, can you find a partial sum of elements in $A$ (or specifically $A_n$) that is greater than $M$?

Comment: @bof Though it wasn't stated explicitly, I believe the purpose of this problem was to show that the sum of an uncountable set of positive numbers can never be finite. This is why I assumed that the elements in $A$ that comprise the partial sums were distinct.

Comment: @bof This problem was a homework problem dealing with infimums and supremums.

Comment: @bof That's what I was wondering too, but I don't think it matters since we are taking the set of all partial sums.

Comment: @Puzzled417 It does matter. The question is reduced to "showing that an uncountable set has more than 1 element" if $a_i$ is not assumed to be distinct.

Comment: @Puzzled417 This sounds like a good clarification to ask your professor. It is quite possible she or he meant for the terms to be distinct and did not specify that.

Comment: @BigbearZzz We are taking the set of all partial sums, so whether we include the ones which have the same elements or not shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Puzzled417 It matters because, if repeated terms are allowed in the sum, the problem has a trivial answer which was not intended. If your teacher gave the problem without specifying "no repetitions", then if I were you I would tactfully mention it to him or her.

Comment: @Puzzled417 It does make a difference. Consider a set $A$ that is very far from being uncountable: $A=\{1\}$. If we take the set of all partial sums of elements in $A$ in which the elements must be _distinct_ we get just two partial sums: $0$ (the empty sum) and $1$. If we allow repeats, we get $0,1,2,\dots$ as we can add $1$ as many times as we like. Clearly one set of partial sums is bounded and the other is not.

Comment: @Puzzled417 In the case that $A$ is uncountable, certainly both sets of sums are unbounded, but the sets of sums are _different_ and thus the method of proof will be different. My proof is based on the assumption that the terms are distinct (though it certainly works if repeats are allowed). As has been mentioned, if repeats are allowed it suffices to find one nonzero element in $A$.

Comment: @kccu I think we should take the case that the $a_i$ are distinct.

Comment: @kccu How does there exist $n$ such that $A_n$ is infinite?

Comment: @Puzzled417 See my answer - in the case that every $A_n$ is finite, we reach a contradiction (namely that $A$ is countable).

Comment: @kccu How are they both countable sets?

Comment: @Puzzled417 As countable unions of finite sets are countable. If $A_1,A_2,\dots$ are all finite, we can list the elements of $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ by first listing all the elements of $A_1$, then all the elements of $A_2$, and so on. Adding in $\{0\}$ doesn't make a difference - the set is still countable.

Comment: @kccu Can you tell me how to continue from the $M>0$ part?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Given that $A_n$ is infinite, you have infinitely many elements in $A$ that are $\geq \frac{1}{n}$. How many of them do you have to add up to make their sum greater than $M$? More explicitly, if you choose $k$ of them, call them $a_1,\dots,a_k$, then $a_1+\cdots+a_k \geq \underbrace{\frac{1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}_k=\frac{k}{n}$. What should $k$ be so that $\frac{k}{n}>M$? Do you know you can choose that many distinct elements from $A_n$?

Answer (score 0):

I can prove it by contradiction.

Suppose $B=\displaystyle \left \{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\Big|a_1,\cdots,a_n \in A,\ n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\right \}$ is bounded, here $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ need to be distinct. In other words, there exists a positive $M$ such that $\forall n\ge1,a_1,\cdots,a_n,\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\le M$. So that all series from $B$ have upper bound $M$, let $M$ be its supremum, then $\forall \{a_i\}\subset A,\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i \le M$.

Since $A$ is uncountable, the series $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$ in $A$ is also uncountable, let $C=\displaystyle \left \{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i\Big|a_i\in A\right \}$, then $C$ is a uncountable set in $[0,M]$. For convenience, let $M=1$.

Now, choose series $\{c_{jk}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{ijk} \Big| c_{jk} \in C\}^{\infty}_{k=1} \subset [\frac{1}{j+1},\frac{1}{j}]$, $j\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, where $\# \{c_{jk}\}^{\infty}_{k=1}$ may be finite or zero.

Then, we can construct a new serie $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_{jk} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{ijk}$, which is an element of $C$, but has value of $\infty$.

Contradiction.